# Get Max Value from MYSQL Result Data

Tags: php, mysql

I've returned some data of last 7 days from Wordpress DB using MySQL which contains the number of views and downloads against each post ID.

Now I want to print the max number of downloads and maximum number of views against the date, along with all the data.

My code is:

```
$statquery = "
SELECT * 
  FROM wp_dstats 
 WHERE postid = $postid 
 ORDER 
    BY date ASC 
 LIMIT 7
";

$statsdata = $wpdb->get_results( $statquery );
if (count($statsdata) >= 1)
{
    // PRINT MAX DOWNLOADS AND MAX VIEWS WITH DATE HERE
    foreach($statsdata as $stats)
    {
        $views = $stats->views;
        $downloads = $stats->downloads;
        $date = $stats->date;
        echo $date.' - Views: '.$views.' | Downloads: '.$downloads,'<br />';
    }
}
```

All the data gets printed as per my requirement, but I also want to print the max downloads and max views.

Comment: you could make a separate query which gets the MAX values via SQL. https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-max-function/

Comment: iterate through the data initially to build the max statistics before printing each detail?

Comment: Also see about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create 2 vars to store max DL and max View and other 2 vars to stores their dates

check the value for each rows, and print them after the loop.

```
$statquery = "SELECT * FROM wp_dstats WHERE postid = $postid ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 7";
$statsdata = $wpdb->get_results( $statquery );

//declare vars
$max_vw = $max_dl = 0; // sorry can't remember how to declare PHP var
$max_vw_dt = $max_dl_dt = '';

if (count($statsdata) >= 1){
  foreach($statsdata as $stats){
    // CHECK AND STORE MAX DL & MAX VIEW
    if($stats->downloads > $max_dl){
      $max_dl = $stats->download;
      $max_dl_dt = $stats->date;
    }
    if($stats->views > $max_vw){
      $max_vw = $stats->views;
      $max_vw_dt = $stats->date;
    }

    // PRINT ALL RECORDS HERE    
    $views = $stats->views;
    $downloads = $stats->downloads;
    $date = $stats->date;
    echo $date.' - Views: '.$views.' | Downloads: '.$downloads.'<br />'; // you have a typo here: , -> should be .
  }
  // PRINT MAX DOWNLOADS AND MAX VIEWS WITH DATE HERE
  echo 'Max Download is '. $max_dl . ' on Date: ' . $max_dl_dt;
  echo 'Max Download is '. $max_vw . ' on Date: ' . $max_vw_dt;
}
```